# EJB Timer : put in a method with Exception, the @Timeout annotation

Tags: java, exception, timer, ejb-3.0

Good morning everybody,
I write you because i want to create an EJB timer. 
But my @Timeout annotated method must throw an application exception. 
And i see in documentation that a @Timeout method can't throw an application exception.

```
   @Stateless@Local
   @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED)
   public class AccesCacheImpl implements AccesCache {

        @Resource
        private TimerService serviceMinuteur;

       // i have to make an updateDataBase every 30 minutes
        public void creerTimer() {
          serviceMinuteur.createTimer(1000, 1800000, "MinuteurCache");
        }

        public void detruireTimer() {
            Timer timerCourant;
            for (final Object timer : serviceMinuteur.getTimers()) {
                timerCourant = (Timer) timer;
                if ("MinuteurCache".equals(timer)) {
                 timerCourant.cancel();
             }
        }
       }

         @Timeout
         public void updateDataBase(final Timer pTimer) throws AccesNomenclatureException {
             .....
             .....
             .....
         }

}
```

I begin in EJB programming : do you find my code OK ? 
And i have necessary to keep this exception. 
Have you faced such a problem ? 
Thank you very much.

Comment: In the @Timeout annotated method updateDataBase, <br>

Comment: In the @Timeout annotated method updateDataBase, i will maybe insert a try catch who catch the Exception. But i want to find a way, if possible, to keep this apllication exception throwing. Because, with the try catch, i "remove" the application exception.

Comment: The java documentation indicate that Timeout callback methods must not throw application exceptions. But i want use the @Timeout annotation for a method and i want that this method, if possible, if possible of course, throw an exception. Have you please an idea to conciliate these 2 facts ? Thank you very much. Thomas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Application exceptions are intended to provide convey additional information to the caller. In this case, the caller of an `@Timeout` method is the EJB container, which cannot know the intent of your application exception, so they are not allowed. If you need to signal failure to the container so that it will retry, I recommend catching the `AccesNomenclatureException` and rethrowing it as `EJBException`, which is a system exception rather than an application exception. Otherwise, if you just want to ignore the failure, then catch it and log it rather than rethrowing it.

Comment: bkail, i wanted to mark your answer but i can't because my reputation is too low.

Comment: @Thomas You accepted the answer, which is all you needed to do, thanks :-).